# Getting TKey from a dictionary with common values where TValue is List<string>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    {"a" , new List<string> { "Red","Yellow"} },
    {"b" , new List<string> { "Blue","Red"} },
    {"c" , new List<string> { "Green","Orange"} },
    {"d" , new List<string> { "Black","Green"} },
};
```

I need output as a dictionary from the `dict` where common value in the `List<string>` should be the key and the value should be the list of keys.

E.g.:

```
Red: [a,b]
Green: [c,d]
```

I don't know how to solve this problem with **`list`** in **`dictionary`** as **`TValue`**.

Please explain me how to handle lists with in dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of looping... Loop over the dictionary, then loop over each value in the list.

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

// Loop through each key/value pair in the dictionary
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    // kvp.Key is the key ("a", "b", etc)
    // kvp.Value is the list of values ("Red", "Yellow", etc)

    // Loop through each of the values
    foreach (var value in kvp.Value)
    {
        // See if our results dictionary already has an entry for this
        // value. If so, grab the corresponding list of keys. If not,
        // create a new list of keys and insert it.
        if (!result.TryGetValue(value, out var list))
        {
            list = new List<string>();
            result.Add(value, list);
        }

        // Add our key to this list of keys
        list.Add(kvp.Key);
    }
}
```

If you want to filter this by entries which have more than one item, then you can do:

```
result = result.Where(x => x.Value.Count > 1).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Alternatively, you can avoid loops and use Linq instead:

```
// Flatten the dictionary into a set of tuples
// e.g. (a, Red), (a, Yellow), (b, Blue), (b, Red), etc
var result = dict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(color => (key: kvp.Key, color)))
    // Group by the value, taking the color as the elements of the group
    // e.g. (Red, (a, b)), (Yellow, (a)), etc
    .GroupBy(item => item.color, item => item.key)
    // Filter to the ones with more than one item
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    // Turn it into a dictionary, taking the key of the grouping
    // (Red, Green, etc), as the dictionary key
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```

You can also use linq query syntax, which is slightly longer but avoids the mess around the `SelectMany`:

```
var result =
    (
        from kvp in dict
        from color in kvp.Value
        group kvp.Key by color into grp
        where grp.Count() > 1
        select grp
    ).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

Comment: In the `foreach` loop it doesn't allow me to initialize the `list` in the `TryGetValue()` method. So i have do that before, why is it so?

Comment: @Watarap you're using an older C# version. "Out variables" were introduced in C# 7.0.

Comment: @canton7 I am using .NET framework 4.7.2 so I think c# v7.0 plus. Out works for me it doesn't allow me declare like this `if (!result.TryGetValue(value, out var list))` . I have to declare the list variable `List<string> list; if (!result.TryGetValue(value, out list))` in order for it to compile.

Comment: @Watarap You'll need Visual Studio 2017 for C# 7.0. Make sure it's selected in Project -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Language version. It doesn't matter though - it's fine to do what you did, and the result is the same.

Comment: @canton7 you are right I am actually using c# 6.0 in Visual studio 2015 just checked it. One last question why does it throw **Object must implement IConvertible** while using it. This project is not Console application based and I couldn't figure out what causes this error.

Comment: @Watarap what throws that exception exactly? The code I posted doesn't - I ran it before I posted it.

Answer (score 5):

You can flattern your dictionary with `SelectMany` and get plain list that looks like

```
"a" - "Red"
"a" - "Yellow"
"b" - "Blue"
"b" = "Red"
// and so on
```

then group by value and build a new dictionary from those groups. Try this code:

```
var commonValues = dict.SelectMany(kv => kv.Value.Select(v => new {key = kv.Key, value = v}))
    .GroupBy(x => x.value)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.key).ToList());
```